# IronPython getting function name at runtime

Tags: ironpython, introspection

this code:

```
inspect.getsource(F)
```

will return F() sourcecode as string.

How can I retrieve just the name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple:

```
print F.__name__
```